# Why does a descriptor __get__ have access to the object's type but __set__ does not?

Tags: python, python-2.7, descriptor

From https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html:

```
descr.__get__(self, obj, type=None) --> value

descr.__set__(self, obj, value) --> None

descr.__delete__(self, obj) --> None
```

Why does the `__get__` method get access to `type` but the other two don't?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is buried in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors), but I can't quite suss it out.

Comment: From *Learning Python* book: The `__get__` access method additionally receives an owner argument, specifying the class to which the descriptor instance is attached. Its instance argument is either the instance through which the attribute was accessed (for `instance.attr` ), or `None` when the attribute is accessed through the owner class directly (for `class.attr` ). The former of these generally computes a value for instance access, and the latter usually returns `self` if descriptor object access is supported.

Comment: So why doesn't the same thing occur with `__set__` and `__delete__`?

Comment: I guess that's because when you set or delete some attribute of a *class*, you simply set/delete it without going through the descriptor?

Answer (score 4):

In `__get__` the `type` argument is a class name, which is helpful, when accessing an attribute through a class, because in this case `obj` (instance) will be `None`. In `__set__` you don't need `type` argument, because it's not possible to set value of a descriptor through a class, you will just overwrite a descriptor with new value.

Consider following code

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    """A data descriptor that sets and returns values
       normally and prints a message logging their access.
    """

    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print 'Retrieving', self.name
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print 'Updating', self.name
        self.val = val

>>> class MyClass(object):
...     x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')
...     y = 5
...
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.x
Retrieving var "x"
10
>>> m.x = 20
Updating var "x"
>>> MyClass.x  # accessing descriptor x through class
Retrieving var "x"
20
>>> MyClass.x = 20  # class parameter x is overwritten with value 20, it's not a descriptor any more
>>>
```

Comment: Indeed, `__get__` has an unusual status as working in a way as both an instance method and a class method depending on how the descriptor is accessed.

Comment: This is *not* setting and retrieving values "normally".  You are setting them on the descriptor it*self*, which is shared between all instances of `MyClass`!